# Gulp + Browserify Webapp - How to include Bootstrap CSS files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, browserify

I am following [this](http://omarfouad.com/blog/2015/03/21/advanced-angularjs-structure-with-gulp-node-and-browserify/) tutorial. I could manage to browserify the bootstrap JS files, but I was wondering how can I add the bootstrap css to my config. I know that files are in node_modules folder, but how can I add them to the build workflow I already have?

gulpfile.js

```
...
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./sass/style.sass')
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
})

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    // Grabs the app.js file
    return browserify('./app/app.js')
        // bundles it and creates a file called main.js
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        // saves it the public/js/ directory
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
})
...
```

app.js:

```
require('angular')
require('bootstrap')

var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 100%;" ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to include the file in your style.sass. You have to mention the full path of the file

Comment: I've tried that and doesn't work. Because node_modules folder is not available at runtime. I need to require the css at build time.